# Using Ajax in netbeans

Tags: java, ajax, jsp, netbeans-7

Is AJAX a hard program to use within netbeans, following tutorials and none of them work within netbeans. Trying to do tutorials below but in netbeans
http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_aspphp.asp
Anyone know any simple Ajax netbeans tutorials?. (Using JSP if possible)

I already use the Dao and have written the servlet and don't want to change them for Ajax

Comment: Note: NetBeans is just an IDE, ajax is a technology for web applications. You can write a web application that uses ajax even using a plain text editor like notepad or vi.

Comment: exactly what version f netbeans you are using?

Comment: I am using netbeans 7.4